# Number of football fans in a town Coursera question, why will it terminate?

Tags: computer-science, invariance

I've come to a problem while doing the Mathematical thinking Course on Coursera.

The problem statement is:

There are two football teams in a town. Each of the citizens is supporting one of the teams. If among someone's friends there are more fans of another team, than of his own, this person tend to switch to supporting the other team. Each day one of such persons switch. Is it possible that this switching process goes forever (assume that friendship is always mutual and that the population of the city and friendship do not change)?

And here's the instructor's explanation:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/what-is-a-proof/lecture/9kr3d/termination

He makes an assumption that if a friend of a friend switches sides, they will not affect the number of one's friends team preference and make one go back and forth indefinitely.

Comment: that isn't a good link...you have to sign up to watch it.  But surely the point is simple.  on day $i$ let $N(i)$ be the number of opposite team friendships.  Then the process you described can only lower $N(i)$, and as this can not go on forever, the process must terminate.

Comment: Why should it only be lowered? One can come up with a case where it stays the same.

Comment: No, you can't (unless the process has terminated).  The rules tell us that nobody switches unless a majority of their friends favor the other team, and the rules tell us that somebody switches.  That means that somebody has a majority of friends on the opposite side and by switching that will lower the number of opposite friendships.

Comment: Now their matching friends have other friends who can influence their own position, right? 
So if some the majority friend group switch sides, then the guy who just switched will switch back.

Comment: So what?  All that matters is that $N(i)$ goes down with each switch.  And that is obvious.  The only relevant group (on that day) is the group containing the switcher, and he is joining the majority.  Please exhibit a precise numerical example if you think I am missing some phenomenon.